# why the problem occurs update git 1.8 to 2.20 CentOS 7.6

Tags: git, centos, centos7

When updating, I execute commands. 
Produces the following error.
Error from update git 1.8 to 2.20. CentOS 7.6
How do I install the required dependencies.

```
# ./configure
checking for library containing clock_gettime... none required
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC... yes
checking for setitimer... yes
checking for library containing setitimer... none required
checking for strcasestr... yes
checking for library containing strcasestr... none required
checking for memmem... yes
checking for library containing memmem... none required
checking for getdelim... yes
checking for library containing getdelim... none required
checking for BSD sysctl... no
checking for POSIX Threads with ''... no
checking for POSIX Threads with '-mt'... no
checking for POSIX Threads with '-pthread'... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.mak.autogen
config.status: executing config.mak.autogen commands
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
#git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
# make
SUBDIR git-gui
MSGFMT po/pt_pt.msg make[1]: *** [po/pt_pt.msg] Error 127
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executed the following commands from the directory /git-2.20.1:

```
yum install gettext
yum install gettext-devel
yum install curl-devel
./configure
make
make install
#git --version
git version 2.20.1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the localization and internationalization libraries.  Either install them using your package manager (yum) or build without them:

`make NO_GETTEXT=1`

Comment: This libraries?                                                                                              
      `icu.x86_64 : International Components for Unicode`,        
      `cal10n.noarch : Compiler assisted localization library (CAL10N)
`